# Mark keywords/words as not important to Webmasters

Tags: seo, google-search-console, keywords

I have a word repeating many times in every page which has no content or keyword significance - the word 'clear' on 'clear filters' button - and I noticed that this word is third in the `keywords` panel. This word has no relevance to the actual content and I supposed it shouldn't be in the `keywords` list.

Is there a way to mark words like this one as not important or not relevant?

On the other hand, is the `keywords` panel that important or I shouldn't bother at all?

I also want to add that this word is in a link which I have marked as `nofollow` once I noticed how high it was on the `keywords` list. But I don't know if it makes any difference.

I'm willing to explain further if I was not clear enough.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Just forget everything you just said. It doesn't matter, forget the 'keywords' panel (whatever that is). Keyword frequency on pages went out the window years ago.

Everything you're trying to do is for the benefit of a search engine (in your eyes) and this is the wrong approach. Just create for the visitors on your website. Whether the word 'clear' is the 3rd mentioned word on the page is neither here nor there and irrelevant.

Just make sure your content serves value and is relevant.